# Numeric Analysis Interpolation of $f(x) , f'(x) $

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

There is a problem i'm finding quite difficult to solve, i'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution :

We want to interpolate the function $f(x)$ and it's derivative $f'(x)$ s.t $f(x_0)=P_2(x_0), f'(x_1)=P_2'(x_1 )$ and $f(x_2)=P_2(x_2 )$

Assuming $x_0 \ne x_2 $ , prove there exists one and only $P_2(x)$ iff $x_1\ne (x_0+x_1)/2$

I'd mention that representing $P_2(x)$ in the standard form is recommended.

Comment: $P_2$ is a polynomial of degree $2$? If it is, just write $P_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and use that in your equations.

Comment: @xavierm02 That's exactly what i've done. I've ended up with three equations of this form (the first and second for $f(x_0),f(x_2)$ and the third one for $f'(x_1)$ , but I did not figure out what to do with those equations.

Comment: You should have linear equations. Try to put them in matrix form.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some hints:**

Let $P_2(x) := ax^2 + bx + c$, then we have $P_2'(x) = 2ax + b$. So for $x_0 \neq x_2$:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
2x_1 & 1 & 0 \\
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b\\
c \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0) \\
f'(x_1)\\
f(x_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
\det \begin{bmatrix}
x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
2x_1 & 1 & 0 \\
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1\
\end{bmatrix} = x_0^2 - 2x_0x_1 + 2x_1x_2 - x_2^2
\end{align}
So for $x_1= \frac{x_0+x_2}{2}$:
\begin{align}
x_0^2 - 2x_0x_1 + 2x_1x_2 - x_2^2 = x_0^2 - x_0^2 - x_0x_2 + x_2x_0 + x_2^2 - x_2^2 = 0
\end{align}
Which means that for $x_1= \frac{x_0+x_2}{2}$ there is no solution for your interpolation problem.

Comment: That's a great solution, thanks.